# Tips for optimizing my Keras Model

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models, tensorflow, keras

I´m developing a regression Model in Keras for R.
I have only 377 observations wich is a huge problem.
As predictors I want to use 1415 biological measuring points from about 60 genes with values between 0-1. I want to predict test values of a psychometrical test with values between 1-20.
My Problem is that I get very mixed results with correlation between test and predicted test up to .5 but a lot of models failing to generalize and predicting a single value with my super basic model architecture but I have no glue how to optimize it. I hope some of you experienced data scientists can hint me to some optimization.
I can imagine that for good advice more information is necessary - I will provide those gladly.
I am very grateful for every tip!

```
train.index <- createDataPartition(data.set$audit_total.FU2, p = .9, list = FALSE)
train <- data.set[ train.index,]
test  <- data.set[-train.index,]

train.y <- train$value
train.x <- asNumericMatrix(train[pr.selection])

test.y <- test$value
test.x <- asNumericMatrix(test[pr.selection])

model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(dim(train.x)[2])) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'relu')


model %>% compile(
  loss = 'mean_squared_error',
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  metrics = c('mean_squared_error')
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  train.x, train.y,
  epochs = 200, batch_size = 32, 
  #validation_split = 0.05,
  verbose = 0
)

train.y.pred <- model %>% predict(train.x)
test.y.pred  <- model %>% predict(test.x)

#Model Performance on Training Data
cor.train <- cor.test(train.y.pred,train.y)
# Model Performance on Testing Data
cor.test <- cor.test(test.y.pred,test.y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you have more predictors than training cases you are in trouble. I would try to simplify the model by using only the most important predictors to your problem. If you cannot get more data I would try to 'clean' the existing data by removing non relevant predictors and keeping only the most predictive ones. Moreover, if your data is so limited I wouldn't start with a neural network as a model because it is very likely to overfit the data. Try using a simple model like regression models etc.

**Edit:** Removing non relevant predictors is a non trivial task which is ususally problem dependent. You can think intuitively (if applicable) which predictors are more related to the physics of your problem and start working with them. Then add one predictor at a time and see if it improves your validation score. If so, add it and if not you can discard it.

One more method is to look at the correlation between each predictor and your target and choose the X% of the best correlated features. 
As I stated before this matter is really problem dependent and there are a lot of heuristics regarding how to overcome this.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer begs the question: exactly *how* do you propose finding "the most important predictors" or "removing non relevant predictors"??